# How can I make the image full bleed but pad the content

Tags: css

My HTML markup is mainly paragraphs, uls & headings. I can't edit the markup but I'd love to pad the content 40px but make the image full width so -40px left and -40px right.

What's the best way to achieve this without jQuery?

```css
p,
h2 {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

img {
  margin-left: -40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>But how? Genius in the Sperm Whale? Has the Sperm Whale ever written a book, spoken a speech?</p>

<p>Champollion deciphered the wrinkled granite hieroglyphics. But there is no Champollion to decipher the Egypt of every man's and every being's face.</p>
<p><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/163/536/354.jpg?hmac=n2PYO9vvS48HLf1RW7MB27ZvPxK5nhLT3sTTcVIqDtw" /></p>
<h2>If the Sperm Whale be physiognomically a Sphinx</h2>

<p>In the full-grown creature the skull will measure at least twenty feet in length. Unhinge the lower jaw, and the side view of this skull is as the side of a moderately inclined plane resting throughout on a level base.</p>

<p>It is plain, then, that phrenologically the head of this Leviathan, in the creature's living intact state, is an entire delusion.</p>
```

The layout is fluid so I don't really want to fix widths if I can help it.

Comment: Remove margin-left:-40px, and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your CSS to have this:

```
p, h2 {
    padding:0 40px 0 40px; /*Just so that we can see why I added the 80px. (top, right, bottom, left)*/
}

img {
    margin-left: -40px; /*-40px to make up for the parent's padding to the left*/
    width: calc(100% + 80px); /*You need to change to this.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the amount of padding, here is more generic solution. It doesn't matter how much padding you have.

```
img {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}
```

```css
p,
h2 {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}
```

```html
<p>But how? Genius in the Sperm Whale? Has the Sperm Whale ever written a book, spoken a speech?</p>

<p>Champollion deciphered the wrinkled granite hieroglyphics. But there is no Champollion to decipher the Egypt of every man's and every being's face.</p>
<p><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/163/536/354.jpg?hmac=n2PYO9vvS48HLf1RW7MB27ZvPxK5nhLT3sTTcVIqDtw" /></p>
<h2>If the Sperm Whale be physiognomically a Sphinx</h2>

<p>In the full-grown creature the skull will measure at least twenty feet in length. Unhinge the lower jaw, and the side view of this skull is as the side of a moderately inclined plane resting throughout on a level base.</p>

<p>It is plain, then, that phrenologically the head of this Leviathan, in the creature's living intact state, is an entire delusion.</p>
```

Also works with a `max-width` container.

```css
p,
h2 {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

p {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
}
```

```html
<p>But how? Genius in the Sperm Whale? Has the Sperm Whale ever written a book, spoken a speech?</p>

<p>Champollion deciphered the wrinkled granite hieroglyphics. But there is no Champollion to decipher the Egypt of every man's and every being's face.</p>
<p>
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/163/536/354.jpg?hmac=n2PYO9vvS48HLf1RW7MB27ZvPxK5nhLT3sTTcVIqDtw" /></p>
<h2>If the Sperm Whale be physiognomically a Sphinx</h2>

<p>In the full-grown creature the skull will measure at least twenty feet in length. Unhinge the lower jaw, and the side view of this skull is as the side of a moderately inclined plane resting throughout on a level base.</p>

<p>It is plain, then, that phrenologically the head of this Leviathan, in the creature's living intact state, is an entire delusion.</p>
```