# how change the Max-widht of the body in a div

Tags: html, css

hy,
in my body I put a max-widht:900px, but I want create a div with a background color that cover all widht of the screen.

tx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66886379/10698741 ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a max-width on your body but rather a container inside your body as that is then doing exactly that and making everything inside your body fit that width. Instead, I would recommend making a full page wrapper that goes 100vw (view width) have your background color in that and then put a container inside that div with the max-width.

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
  #fullwidth: {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: 'red';
  }

  #container: {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="fullwidth">
   <div id="container">
    // Add content in here
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```